# Can i create non-rectangle window without compositing manager?

Tags: linux, window, x11, xorg

I want to create custom shaped window. I only need to specify which pixels have to be drawn.

When compositing manager is used i can use alpha channel, but without it i don't know how can i do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [xshape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_extension) extension if you really want:)